# Rails 3 - External Anchor with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a small gallery/image application that I'm trying to incorporate some ajax into with Jquery. I'm starting small, turning my anchor tags into ajax. Right now, I have a pagination link, and an image that links to an external url.

Right now, my pagination links are working with ajax, though my image_link will not open it's target url. My index and partial code are as follows:

index.html.erb

```
<div id="galleries">
<%= render 'pictures' %>
</div>
```

and the _pictures.html.erb:

```
<% @galleries.each do |g| %>
    <% for image in g.images %>
    <div id="picture">
      <%= render 'top_nav'%>

<!-- this is the link that does not work w/ ajax -->
      <%= link_to image_tag(image.file_url(:preview)), g.source, :remote => true, :target => "_blank" %> 

      <%= will_paginate(@galleries, :next_label => "Forward", :previous_label => "Previous") %>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="image_description">
      <h2>
      <%= g.title %>,
      <span class="time">
        <%= distance_of_time_in_words(g.created_at, Time.now, include_seconds = false)%> ago
      </span>
      </h2>
    </div>      
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I believe I'm letting ajax take over both the pagination link and external image link by using #picture a, here's my javascript in the application.js:

```
$(function() {
    $("#picture a").live("click", function() {
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

My index.js.erb is as follows:

```
$("#galleries").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("pictures")) %>");
```

For the broke image link, here's what the HTML it outputs:

```
<a target="_blank" data-remote="true" href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="/uploads/image/file/3/preview_Screenshot-2.png?1311699598" alt="Preview_screenshot-2">
</a>
```

But when you click this, it does nothing. My guess is that it's doing something, it's rendering the pictures partial over and over, and doesn't know how to link externally because I've hijacked the link_to's functionality, and i'm telling it in my index.js.erb to just render the partial over and over? Anyway, I need help writing this external link as an ajax link as I'd eventually like to call a model method to update some data on the select/linked images.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the :method symbol in your link_to

```
<%= link_to "destroy", article_path(@article), :method => :delete, :remote => true %>

builds

<a href="/articles/1" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">destroy</a>
```

From [Unobtrusive Javascript in Rails 3](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/)